# Reset Bootstrap 3 Carousel on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, safari, mobile-safari

Has anybody ever run into Bootstrap's carousel not resetting on page load. It seems to be acting weird in Safari on both the desktop and iPads.

On desktops, the slide/tab you leave on is still active if you press the back button and return to the previous page.

On iPads, the slide/tab you leave on is no longer marked as active when you press the back button to return. This is really the larger problem here.

Is there a way to force `data-slide-to='1'` to always be active on page load.

```
$('.carousel.graph').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
});
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var initial = $('table.picker td').attr('data-slide-to', 0);
    initial.addClass('active');
});
```

This did not work.

**EDIT**

Here's my HTML as well...

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide graph" data-ride="carousel">
    <table class="carousel-indicators picker">
        <tr>
            <td class="active" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0">
                <div><span>Slide 1</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1">
                <div><span>Slide 2</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="blank"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2">
                <div><span>Slide 3</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3">
                <div><span>Slide 4</span></div>
            </td>
            <td class="" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="4">
                <div><span>Slide 5</span></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner graph">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="/img/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/img/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/img/3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/img/4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/img/5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that `active` is not being reapplied to the `TD` with `data-slide-to="0"`. I can tell because when a "picker TD" is active it has a different background color. When I press the back arrow on iPads, all the "picker TDs" have the same background color.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.carousel.graph').carousel({
    pause: true,
    interval: false
}).carousel(0);
```

> **.carousel(number)**
>  Cycles the carousel to a particular frame (0 based, similar to an array).

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage